# I would like to salvage some of my recent poorly-received questions

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892756/in-gtk-how-can-i-space-widgets-and-size-text-according-to-window-size-rather-t) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035979/how-do-i-create-gtk2-style-widgets-in-gtk3) are both questions I asked, and needed editing. The premise of the question seems on topic, but I just worded it weirdly. May I have those questions undeleted and/or reopened? I have edited them since they were first deleted.

Now that I think of it, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192791/how-to-make-an-empty-space-between-gtk-widgets) also seems salvageable.

Comment: We cannot have a discussion about these questions on Meta when they are deleted (since most users aren't able to see deleted questions). Furthermore, when they're deleted, no one else but you (and moderators) can edit them. As such, I've taken the liberty of undeleting both of those questions.

Comment: @CodyGray Now that I think of it, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192791/how-to-make-an-empty-space-between-gtk-widgets) also seems salvageable. Could that one be deleted to?

Comment: Perhaps. That one would need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd say. Let's focus on the original two for now.